# MySQL query - weird syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using phpmyadmin and MySQL to run a simple query, that creates a function checking the existence of a certain record. It keeps throwing a `syntax error at line 7 with Declare`. I have no idea why. I did try to use the built-in function creator, but it's messed up and I don't like it. Any help appreciated!

```
CREATE FUNCTION  check_if_card_exists (_name TEXT)
RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA

    BEGIN
    DECLARE res INT; --line 7
    IF EXISTS (SELECT `name` FROM `cards` WHERE `name` = _name)
    THEN SET res = 1;
    ELSE SET res = 0;
    END IF;
    RETURN res;
    END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `check_if_card_exists`$$

CREATE FUNCTION  check_if_card_exists (_name TEXT)
RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA

    BEGIN
    DECLARE res INT; --line 7
    IF EXISTS (SELECT `name` FROM `cards` WHERE `name` = _name)
    THEN SET res = 1;
    ELSE SET res = 0;
    END IF;
    RETURN res;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```